# MVC password field input raises "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client"

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I came around this funny case where a user types a password that contains '<' and '>' symbols.

Having default form validation functionality of MVC 5, I get the error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Password="1 < 2 3 a @ < i O")

*(on the above error I intentionally put spaces in the password value, otherwise it cannot be displayed... it is potentially dangerous indeed...!!!)*

Now, I know that mvc auto encodes the user input to avoid Cross Site Scripting, so in a regular textbox, I would not have such a problem, but in a password field, it is obviously not auto-encoded (as it shouldnt!).

A quick (maybe dirty) workaround would be that I enable `[AllowHtml]` decorator on the password field, on the model.

Another quick (maybe dirtyer) workaround would be that I enable `[ValidateInput(false)]` decorator on the controller action.

But I would like some advice that overcomes my problem and does not open any potential other holes in my system... Any suggestions, please??

Comment: Why is [AllowHtml] a dirty solution for password?

Comment: @lars1595 it is probably dirty because what I want to do is not to allow Html, but to allow some Characters like < and >.

Answer (score 1):

For a login controller, turning off validation is fine. The password will never be displayed, or even stored anywhere, and if you display the username anywhere, you can just make sure it's properly encoded. The standard input validation obviously has no idea how you're using the data that's been entered, so has to be fairly paranoid. It's not as if turning it off, where necessary, automatically makes your application less secure.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yet, I think that if what you say was true, then the MVC would have deactivated by default the validation on the password fields... there must be some special option... i.e. a decorator stating "AllowSpecialCharacters" on the password field, or something like that

Comment: What about on the setpassword() action?

Comment: What about it Alan? Can you elaborate please?